# ggplot2 100% pie chart error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having problem with the pie chart in ggplot. 
Here is example of the code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

overtime.by.dow <- structure(list(dow = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", 
"Sat"), class = "factor"), Overtime = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(2L, 48L, 0L, 51L, 0L, 50L, 0L, 50L, 44L, 6L), Percent = c(4, 
    96, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 88, 12), Per.txt = c("2\n4%", 
    "48\n96%", "0\n0%", "51\n100%", "0\n0%", "50\n100%", "0\n0%", 
    "50\n100%", "44\n88%", "6\n12%"), txt.pos = c(2, 52, 0, 50, 
    0, 50, 0, 50, 44, 94), cumsum = c(4, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 
    0, 100, 88, 100)), .Names = c("dow", "Overtime", "Freq", 
"Percent", "Per.txt", "txt.pos", "cumsum"), row.names = c(2L, 
9L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 11L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 13L), class = "data.frame")

      ggplot(data =  overtime.by.dow,
             aes(x="",
                 y=Percent,
                 fill = Overtime)) +
      geom_bar(width = 1) +
      facet_wrap(~dow) +
      xlab('') +
      geom_text(aes(y = txt.pos, label = Per.txt)) +
      coord_polar(theta = "y") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c('green', 'red'))
```

I get the following error. I think the problem is because i have some pies with 100%. The code will be part of automatic process, and 100% pies are likely, and I do want to show them. Is there some trick that will allow to have 100% pies?

```
Error in lf$dist[idx] <- spiral_arc_length(lf$slope[idx], lf$tn1[idx],  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

Comment: possibly useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2-dev/orGTdSeQB7I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding small number to zero

```
overtime.by.dow$Percent[overtime.by.dow$Percent == 0] <- 0.01
```